# How to validate mixed effect logistic model and ordered mixed logistic regression

Tags: mixed-model

I would like to validate my mixed effect logistic model and ordered mixed logistic regression. How we can say that it is valid?

For example can we used Stukel’s goodness of fit test or Hosmer-Lemeshow? They are popular for logistic regression goodness of fit test, but how about when data is clustered?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus What are the assumption of mixed effect logist regression model? if I want to check the validity of model what I should consider? I know that the stata code questiuon is not relevent here, but maybe some command examples in stata would explain that.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus or in other words, how to validate a binary or an ordered mixed logistic model?

Comment: This seems like a basic question. Is there some particular pitfall or obstruction that makes this difficult for you and that we should be aware of or focus on? Did you already look up yourself what these assumptions are, e.g. the regular Wikipedia page about logistic regression and mixed models, and why did this not help?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus for the ordinary logistic or ordered logistic regression I know, but I dont find when data is longitudinal and outcome is binary or categorical. Could you please give me the link in case?

Comment: could you update this in your question

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "assumptions' and what you are aiming for. The assumptions can be a large list, and including basic things as 'sampling has occured independent and without bias' and it can be tricky to check those assumptions. And longitudinal study, that is a very broad subject.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus please see the updates